# Is there a way to list all repositories in a Git Organization using Libgit2sharp?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Is there a way to list all repositories in a Git Organization using Libgit2sharp?

I did check here https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki.

But seems like there are no wiki pages explaining "working with Git Organization"!

Answer (score 2):

Libgit2sharp is a C# library for git. Git Organizations however are a GitHub construct and will be available only via the Github API.

So the solution would be to write your own code to that integrates Libgit2sharp and the GitHub API